# Is there a way to control SDR content brightness in windows over a command line in order to assign it to some kind of macro?

Tags: macros, registry, hdr, screen-brightness

I would like to control the SDR content [Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhQVi.png) from windows through some kind of script or command line, to bind it to a macro wheel on my keyboard, is it possible?

The DWORD value that shows the SDRWhiteLevel value of my monitor only seems to work one way, and won't update the actual brightness when edited through the registry.

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\MonitorDataStore<yourmonitor>\SDRWhiteLevel

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.